# Returning all rows from a multidimensional df that match MULTIPLE conditions (python)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm not entirely new to programming, but I *am* new to working with multidimensional data structures. I apologise if this is overly simplistic, but I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now, and would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction...

I have:

1. **big_df** --> A df consisting of ~3,000,000 rows and ~80 columns. Three of these columns contain coordinate data X, Y, Z
2. **arr** --> A separate 3d array of X, Y, Z data, containing ~4000 data points

My goal is to create a new df containing the rows from **big_df** where **big_df(X,Y,Z) == arr(X,Y,Z)**

I've tried many, many different approaches, and I know I could iterate through and match that way... but that would be super inefficient, and there's definitely a vectorised solution.

This is where I'm at currently:

```
result = big_df.loc[(big_df["X"] == arr[:, 0]) 
                  & (big_df["Y"] == arr[:, 1]) 
                  & (big_df["Z"] == arr[:, 2]))]
```

This particular version is returning 1 row, when I know that there are 4075 matches....

I've tried several orientations of this, but in each case I get something... just not what I need...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
ar = big_df[["X", "Y", "Z"]]
```

Comment: I want access to all of the data in the big_df columns, but ONLY where big_df["X", "Y", "Z"] == arr[X,Y,Z].     So I should end up with a new df of ~4000 rows and ~80 columns. If that makes sense?? :/